# MediaWiki custom canonical for a page?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm using $wgEnableCanonicalServerLink to generate canonicals.

Plus this solution to serve the main page from the domain root: https://laxstrom.name/blag/2015/08/31/mediawiki-short-urls-with-nginx-and-main-page-without-redirect

My problem is that the main page loaded at http://www.example.com/ domain root still has the long path as the canonical in the source.

Is it possible to set a custom canonical for a page, or solve this issue some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I set:

```php
$wgMainPageIsDomainRoot = true;
$wgEnableCanonicalServerLink = true;
```

in my `LocalSettings.php`, the canonical url of my main page is the document root.

Comment: `$wgMainPageIsDomainRoot = true;` worked indeed thanks (had to upgrade, only supported from MediaWiki v1.34.0)